# using the word "meaning" in a sentence to explain

Tags: word-usage, writing-style, tech-writing

I have the following sentence:

> This process is circuitous, meaning, the responsibility returns to the Originator user after all is approved.

A few questions:

1. I know this would be a fully understood sentence in speech, but is it proper to write like this in a User Guide, for example?
2. Is the punctuation correct ?

Comment: I would use "i.e." instead of "meaning".

Answer (score 2):

It looks correct to me, though a better received way of saying the same would be:

> This process is circuitous, which means that the responsibility
>   returns to the Originator user after all is approved.

You could also say "meaning that" instead of "which means that".

Comment: Why this 'isis'!

Comment: It should be a single "is", but I couldn't edit the original post (just removing "is" was too short of an edit to be acceptable), so I just answered the question as is (no pun intended).

Comment: @mahmudkoya, my mistake, I copied that part in after I had already typed "is".@krostd - you can edit your answer.

Answer (score -1):

If you are writing a document that you would hope to have persistence, you should want to use a formal structure.

The sentence above is borderline run-on.  You have two independent clauses connected by (I am not even sure what to call this word used by itself)

To simplify, I would write it as follows:

> This process is circuitous.  (The responsibility returns to the Originator user after all is approved)

If you needed more context, I would go with i.e. instead of meaning.

> This process is circuitous.  (i.e. The responsibility returns to the Originator user after all is approved)

Comment: If someone is unhappy with this answer, I would like to know what it is lacking.